# How to get data from Firebase Database using curl?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i all, 
I’m new to firebase so excuse if my question is too simple!
Really just starting with this…
I simply want to get a value from the database.

I’d like to use terminal on a Mac, and I downloaded everything I need to interact with it.
I can “firebase login” successfully

let’s say this is my database:
https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com
And I want to get the value "1234" from mydatabase/test/serial/“number: 1234"
What should I write in my terminal?

this is my try

```
curl "https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/test/serial.json?auth=CREDENTIAL"
```

BUt, of course, I'm pretty sure I am missing something fundamental...

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a variable in path "https://pfe2020-7e4fc.firebaseio.com/One/1".
[image]
your command will be as follow:
`curl 'https://pfe2020-7e4fc.firebaseio.com/One/1.json'`
 You can refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli for more details.